# Unity: Guidelines to add script to Prefab

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and I'd like to know what's the best way to add a script to a Prefab.
I currently see two ways of doing so:

1) Use the Unity interface to add it to an existing prefab

2) Use the AddComponent following the code which instantiates the prefab

I try using the 2) everywhere as I am using git to source control my code and I think conflicts may be easier to resolve inside code (compare to inside .prefab files by instance). But I may be wrong.

Is there any unity good practice regarding this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's indeed the only two ways to add a component to a GameObject.

The primary way you are expected to add components to GameObjects is the Unity interface. Being able to setup logic and data through the interface rather than code is one of the big benefits of using such a game engine. It gives you flexibility and it smooths the process for quite a number of operations.

`AddComponent` use leans more toward adding a component to change the behavior of an existing GameObject or to create a GameObject from scratch, both at runtime. Most people usually don't make an use of it.

Git handles .prefab merging just fine. These are basically just text files with tags and structure so that it can be interpreted by the engine and be readable for an user (think of XML files).